# R - cut data from data frame to balance it

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 2600 entries, which are spread in 249 factor levels (persons). The data set is not well balanced.

[image]

I would like to delete all entries which have less than 5 occurrences in one factor. Also I would like to trim those which have more than 5 occurrences down to 5. So in the end I want to have a data frame with less overall entries, but which is balanced over the factor person.

The data set is built as follows:

```
file_list <- list.files("path/to/image/folder", full.names=TRUE) 
# the folder contains 2600 images, which include information about the 
# person factor in their file name

file_names <- sapply(strsplit(file_list , split = '_'), "[",  1)
person_list <- substr(file_names, 1 ,3)
person_class <- as.factor(person_list)

imageWidth = 320; # uniform pixel width of all images
imageHeight = 280; # uniform pixel height of all images
variableCount = imageHeight * imageWidth + 2

images <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq(count),nrow=count,ncol=variableCount ))
images[1] <- person_class
images[2] <- eyepos_class

for(i in 1:count) {
  img <- readJPEG(file_list[i])
  image <- c(img)
  images[i, 3:variableCount] <- image
}
```

[image]

So basically I need to get the amount of samples per factor level (like when using `summary(images[1])` and then perform operations to trim the data set.
I don't really know how to start here and any help is appreciated

Comment: I know that your data is not tiny, but in order to write a good question that's reproducible which will get you upvotes and answers, please include reproducible that we can copy and paste to reproduce your data/problem and reproduce your problem. You can use a built-in dataset or create your own and include the code you used.

Comment: Well I did my best to make it reproducible, but still the data set would be needed, which is available publicly but download speed is slow af

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
res <- setDT(images)[, if(.N > = 5) head(.SD, 5) , by = V1]
```

Comment: This seems to work (reduces data set from 2639 -> 1090 objects). Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can tell me why `plot(res$V1)` is working after that, but `plot(res[1])` gives an error: `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`? Shouldn't that be the same?

Comment: @4ndro1d Subsetting columns in `data.table` is slightly different `res$V1` is a vector.  You can use `res[[1]]` to get the first column as a vector

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(images, V1) %>%  # group by the V1 column
    filter(n() >= 5) %>%  # keep only groups with 5 or more rows
    slice(1:5)            # keep only the first 5 rows in each group
```

You can assign the result to an object like normal. For example `my_desired_result = group_by(images, ...`

Comment: Do I have to assign the result to some variable? I tried and I get no results. Neither the data frame changed nor can i store something to a variable. But it looks pretty much like what I am looking for.

Comment: When assigning to a variable like this: `res1 <- group_by(images, V1) %>%  # group by the V1 column
  filter(n() >= 5) %>%  # keep only groups with 5 or more rows
  slice(1:5) %>%` the variable res1 isn't even created in my workspace

Comment: Oh, and I also had an extra pipe at the end. That's probably it. Removed now.